# How many people have installed my iPhone app as a result of Facebook ads?

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile, sdk, ads

I've followed the instructions on this page for my Xcode project (iOS app): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

- Create Facebook ad for our iPhone APP
- installed the Facebook SDK for iOS
- obtained Facebook App ID
- configured Xcode project

And I've created and run ads for app installs however how do I know how many people have installed my app as a result of the ads? There is nothing showing top left of the ads page....just zero???? Nothing showing in my Facebook Developer account.

here is the code

```
   [FBSettings setDefaultAppID:@"MY FACEBOOK APP ID"];
   [FBAppEvents activateApp];
```

I've clearly missed a pretty obvious step. Can someone please shed some light?